# Lorentz or restricted Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

We say (or we observe empirically) that the laws of physics are Lorentz invariant, i.e their form does not change under transformations of the Lorentz group.

The weak interactions are not invariant under parity i.e spatial reflections, which are contained in the full Lorentz group. So it seems that many authors use Lorentz group loosely when they really mean restricted Lorentz group, i.e $SO^{+}(1,3)$, the connected component containing the identity, consisting of Lorentz transformations that preserve the orientation of space and direction of time.

If so, when we say the Poincare group is the full symmetry group of any relativistic field theory, we really mean the restricted Poincare group $T(4) \rtimes SO^{+}(1,3)$.

Am I right or misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. for the Wigner classification of elementary particles, we need the restricted Poincaré group. The general transformation property of a (quantum) field involves $\mbox{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$ matrices (thus spinorial fields), so we also have the restricted Lorentz group with a prominent role. Of course, according to phenomenology, we can consider different types of spinors, such as the Dirac spinors (which are reducible under restricted Lorentz transformations, but irreducible under the restricted Lorentz transformations plus space inversion) instead of the elementary Weyl ones. We also have genuine 4-vector and 4-tensor fields, but they can always be reached from Weyl spinors either as reducible or irreducible representations of $\mbox{SL}(2, \mathbb C)$.